# regex to edit in order to search multiple words with chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-chosen

I'm using chosen ([chosen website](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html)) to make selectlist more user-friendly and the search function is only searching for one exact word.

I mean that if list contains

- TEST -> Installations Communes
- TEST -> Installations Communes -> Admin Building
- TEST -> Installations Communes -> Parking
- TEST -> Installations Communes -> Little building

and user type

- "Installations", all is OK (User see 4 records)
- "Installations Communes", User see 0 result (because when there is more than 1 word, search is not working)

The search function is

```
escapedSearchText = searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
```

How can I edit this in order to allow user to search for more than 1 word?

Here is the full JS function:

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.winnow_results = function() {
  var escapedSearchText, option, regex, results, results_group, searchText, startpos, text, zregex, _i, _len, _ref;
  this.no_results_clear();
  results = 0;
  searchText = this.get_search_text();
  escapedSearchText = searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
  zregex = new RegExp(escapedSearchText, 'i');
  regex = this.get_search_regex(escapedSearchText);
  _ref = this.results_data;
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    option = _ref[_i];
    option.search_match = false;
    results_group = null;
    if (this.include_option_in_results(option)) {
      if (option.group) {
        option.group_match = false;
        option.active_options = 0;
      }
      if ((option.group_array_index != null) && this.results_data[option.group_array_index]) {
        results_group = this.results_data[option.group_array_index];
        if (results_group.active_options === 0 && results_group.search_match) {
          results += 1;
        }
        results_group.active_options += 1;
      }
      if (!(option.group && !this.group_search)) {
        option.search_text = option.group ? option.label : option.text;
        option.search_match = this.search_string_match(option.search_text, regex);
        if (option.search_match && !option.group) {
          results += 1;
        }
        if (option.search_match) {
          if (searchText.length) {
            startpos = option.search_text.search(zregex);
            text = option.search_text.substr(0, startpos + searchText.length) + '</em>' + option.search_text.substr(startpos + searchText.length);
            option.search_text = text.substr(0, startpos) + '<em>' + text.substr(startpos);
          }
          if (results_group != null) {
            results_group.group_match = true;
          }
        } else if ((option.group_array_index != null) && this.results_data[option.group_array_index].search_match) {
          option.search_match = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  this.result_clear_highlight();
  if (results < 1 && searchText.length) {
    this.update_results_content("");
    return this.no_results(searchText);
  } else {
    this.update_results_content(this.results_option_build());
    return this.winnow_results_set_highlight();
  }
};
```

Comment: This has not been my experience. As long as the words are continuous, it should match for more than one word (i.e. "Hello dude" would match "Hello dude" and "Hello dudes". Can you post a jsfiddle with the just the select box you're using?

Comment: Here's my jsfiddle. You can see that it matches exactly as you would expect. There shouldn't be any reason to do anything fancy with regex. https://jsfiddle.net/Lf8uw80g/

Comment: @tobylaroni : huh it's strange... Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RA8ej/168/

Comment: @tobylarony: by putting my options, it doesn't work with your fiddle too

Comment: @tobylaroni no idea why THIS isn't rnning http://jsfiddle.net/RA8ej/168/ ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Even without "->"! see this : http://jsfiddle.net/RA8ej/169/ I can't use search for "Little building" for instance

Comment: @tobylaroni apparently, I can search for multiple words, but ONLY if I start search from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(".chzn-select").chosen({"search_contains": true}); is the solution in order to search even if user type something is not at the beginning of the text

Answer (score 0):

From a pure regexp approach (I don't know chosen), you can try something like:

```
var splitSearchText = searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#]/g, "\\$&").split(' ');
escapedSearchText = ('^((' + splitSearchText.join('|') + ')\\s?){' + splitSearchText.length + '}$');
```

Here is a test to show how it works (not sure the global script works the same):

```js
var searchText = 'abc edf';
var splitSearchText = searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#]/g, "\\$&").split(' ');
var escapedSearchText = ('^((' + splitSearchText.join('|') + ')\\s?){' + splitSearchText.length + '}$');
var zregex = new RegExp(escapedSearchText, 'i');

alert(zregex.test('abc'));
alert(zregex.test('abc bcd'));
alert(zregex.test('abc edf'));
alert(zregex.test('edf abc'));
```

Comment: @Gnucky thanks but it doesn't work in the application :-/

Comment: Ok sorry, maybe you should look at options (group_match, search_match, ...).

Comment: apparently the component must search into phrases so regex isn't the solution (I didn't posted the good question)

Answer (score -1):

You could filter the array using [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var data = [
    "Hello",
    "Hello dude",
    "Hello dudes",
    "Hi dudes"
];

function stringContains(str, value) {
    return str.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

function arrayFilter(arr, value) {

    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1) {

        var subject = arr[i];

        if (stringContains(subject, value)) {
            result.push(subject);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(arrayFilter(data, "Hello")); // ["Hello", "Hello dude", "Hello dudes"]
console.log(arrayFilter(data, "Hello dude")); // ["Hello", "Hello dude"]
```

Or if you don't care about [prehistoric browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5) or using [polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) you could simply use:

```
function arrayFilter(arr, value) {
    return arr.filter(function (subject) {
        return subject.indexOf(value) > -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really a Rube Goldberg approach, and doesn't address the issue of using chosen. I don't want to downvote, but this really is not an appropriate answer to this question, and I would hope that others experiencing issues with chosen would not adopt this as their solution.

Comment: @tobylaroni Why, is it to hard nowadays to write a simple piece of code? It works and it is also faster than using regular expressions.